# MySQL: How to select a column by number?

Tags: mysql, select, syntax

I'm writing a program, and I have the need to `SELECT` column names by number, rather than by name.

That is, say the attributes to my table are:

```
SSN, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Address, City, State, Zip
```

How could I select the data just from columns 0 (SSN), 1 (FirstName), 2(LastName), 6 (State)

Is there a way to do this without delving into `information schema`?

Comment: Why do you have to select by number? That's incredibly poor design if its arbitrary. Or is this homework?

Comment: could you store them in an array and reference the array key?

Comment: I mean, I could keep track of another structure, it would just be easier if I could make the selection directly.  Picked up someone else's code at work, and I don't want to have to redesign a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reconsider your design. A table can be changed, it can evolve, column order is very fickle. You should NOT hardcode column numbers.

---

ADDENDUM

By "evolve" and "fickle", I don't mean that the database engine can move them around. That's pretty much fix. No, I mean that needs can change in the future and the table design can be updated. It will be easier in the future to adapt your old code if you list the actual column names rather than the column position order. Think of column position just like row position: don't expect a particular order in the result based on input order, but rather *make* your query give you the order you need.

Comment: Ah.. I figured this might be the case.  Alright, time to refactor!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so don't do this, but, if you really need to do this you can use COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION in the information schema.

Comment: BTW, if you are looking to do this because a legacy table has reserved words for column names, a common problem, you can simply wrap the column names in quotes.  For example SELECT \`select\` FROM \`select\` is probably legal SQL, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT `0`,`1`,`2`,`6` FROM `table` ORDER BY `ssn`
```